# Java equivalent of strace

Tags: performance, java, c, debugging, strace

When I have an issue with a C application, one of the first tools I reach for is `strace`, I can easily see e.g. if it is blocking on a read from a socket, or for some file I/O or whatever else. But this doesn't work on a Java application as the JVM is spinning away regardless of what the app is doing creating a lot of noise that makes `strace` output impossible to read. What is the equivalent tool in Java-land?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://www.fromdev.com/2008/12/debugging-java-on-unixlinux-my-favorite.html#pstack---check-for-process-stack-trace

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html). It will give you more insight on what's going on inside your JAVA application/JVM.